# cut and join video without rendering

Tags: edit-mode, video

I want to do some simple cutting in middle of video and join remaining parts.
but when rendering the final work, it takes a very long time to finish.
I wish if I could export the final video without re-render it

Comment: Could you please show your sequence editor?

Comment: I dont know if this is possible to export without reencoding with blender, but check out LosslessCut or ffmpeg (https://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg)